# Can't get Facebook's user photos with php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the user photos, but I cannot get the user's photos data.

I'm trying this:

```
$photos = $facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$profileFID.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token);
print_r($photos);
```

I'm sure the URL is correct since pasting it in the browser shows the photos array. However when I try to print the array to check if I got it I get only this:

```
( [id] => https://graph.facebook.com/1409006586/photos )
```

How can I get the full array with the user photos?

Comment: Have you requested the `user_photos` permission?

Comment: yes, I pasted the same URL in the browser and got the array with the latest pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook SDK will take care of constructing the url for you (and append the `access_token`), you just need to build the query:

```
$photos = $facebook->api('me/photos');
```

If the user is not currently logged in but you have the `access_token`, then use:

```
$photos = $facebook->api($profileFID.'/photos', 'get', array('access_token'=>$access_token));
```

P.S: always put your queries in a `try...catch` blocks

Comment: thank you. Just a question, (I believe photos are ordered recent first) how do I set an offset/limit for the query?

Comment: Check the [Graph API **Paging**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) section. You can try it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos%3Flimit%3D2%26offset%3D5).

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/1409006586/`photos`

replace photo by picture

ex 
https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture